# ¿#ERROR AL HACER UNA DIVISIÓN EN LA EXPRESIÓN DE RDLC?

Tags: reportviewer

Tengo esta operacion de porcentaje y funciona con la mayoria, el error esta en hacer division entre cero, como puedo hacer que no me muestre ***#ERROR*** en en vez de eso me muestre ***O*** (cero)

```
G =Fields!E.Value*100/Fields!D.Value
H =Fields!F.Value*100/Fields!D.Value
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ve a la opcion de  **Report -> Report Properties -> Code**
copia y pega

```
Public Function Divide(ByVal first As Double, ByVal second As Double) As Double
        If second = 0 Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return first * 100 / second
        End If
    End Function
```

y en la expresion:

```
= IIF(Fields!D.Value = 0, 0, Code.Divide(Fields!E.Value, Fields!D.Value))

= IIF(Fields!D.Value = 0, 0, Code.Divide(Fields!F.Value, Fields!D.Value))
```